# How to get printer port detail?

Tags: c++, windows, api, printing

I can get to printer port name. Using the GetPrint() and PRINTER_INFO_2 struct.

I want to printer port detail(ex : Local Port, Standard TCP/IP Port, etc).

How to get printer port detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to call [EnumPorts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162687(v=vs.85).aspx) with the [PORT_INFO_2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162823(v=vs.85).aspx) level.  You will then have to search the returned array of PORT_INFO_2 structure for the desired port name. The pDescription field of the PORT_INFO_2 structure contains details on the port.